# Warning:(86, 18) Result of 'Stream.peek()' is ignored

Tags: java, java-stream, compiler-warnings

I have this piece of code :

```
userAvailableRoles.stream()
        .peek(x-> x.setPets(userPets(roles, hasValidAccess)));
```

but I have this warning:

```
Warning:(86, 18) Result of 'Stream.peek()' is ignored
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`peek` returns a stream of elements after the consumer is applied to them. Here, you ignore this returned stream, which produces the warning.

If you just need to call `setPets` on all the elements of `userAvailableRoles` you should probably use [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) and not `peek`:

```java
userAvailableRoles.forEach(x-> x.setPets(userPets(roles, hasValidAccess)));
```

Answer (score 4):

`peek` returns a stream with the same elements for further processing. If you don't need that you should use `forEach` instead.